# Remove all results from google search and restart from scratch

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

the problem with my website is that it has many 404 pages on google , that's why I wanted to remove all the pages from google and restart from the begining .
I have removed all the links from google webmaster tools but now ,when I sent my sitemap it doesn't seem to have any effect 
Does anybody have any idea about this  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google bot should not be forced to deleted pages immediately. You have to let it recrawl your website.

From Google:

> To clean up cruft, like old pages that 404. If you recently changed
>   your site and now have some outdated URLs in the index, Google's
>   crawlers will see this as we recrawl your URLs, and those pages will
>   naturally drop out of our search results. There's no need to request
>   an urgent removal.

There is no need to delete your whole website, and don't do it.

**Be sure** that you send **404 Not Found or better 410 Gone** status on the pages that no longer exist.

Upload a new sitemap, make sure that your website is running correctly and let Google bot recrawl your website for several days

After that period your website will be synced, and no more old pages will be shown on the Google Search Result Pages

Comment: I have soft 404 pages .. What should I do ?

Comment: Nothing, just upload new sitemap and let it run. You will need to  let Google recrawl your site. Depending on how many pages you have it will take less or more time

Comment: What I meant is that My soft 404 pages return 200 http code , it means that google wouldn't recognize them as not found.

Comment: No, you should return 404 or 410 http code. Otherwise these pages will never be removed from Google, and you may be penalized for junk content

Comment: I see I will see how to do this!